# Chinese Characters on table from thift store

Tags: character-identification

Does anyone know what this says? (My apologies if it is not Chinese). [image]

Answer (score 2):

Beautiful scene of a lotus pond.

荷塘: lotus pond.

Source: http://baike.baidu.com/subview/1725417/7633674.htm

秀色: beautiful scene

Source: http://baike.baidu.com/subview/203608/8935087.htm

Comment: Thank you very much. Seems odd to write out what you are showing visually but that is great to know.

Comment: Probably to show off the caligraghy.

Comment: Chinese painting often incorporates calligraphy as part of the composition. It may be a poem, a couplet, or simply a short phrase about what is depicted.